# Lower amps than expected?

Tags: mosfet, inverter, high-voltage, 555, amperage

I build an inverter to power some panels of EL paint (If you don't know what EL paint is check out this [link](http://tdcustoms.com/how-does-lumilor-work/)). It puts out some very high voltage and I thought I'd check to see what amperage it is capable of delivering since the voltages it is operating at are rather dangerous (I measured 329v with my meter). Anyways, I tested the output amperage in several different ways. First I checked the amps on the high side while it was powering the EL panel and got ~874uA, pretty small. What really surprised me was that when there was no load present (direct short) my meter only measured 10.5mA, still pretty small. I would have thought that shorting the ends of the transformer through the meter would have caused bad things to happen, specifically white smoke and a melted transformer, but I experienced nothing of the sort.

I tested it with several different MOSFETs and also tried a small transistor (2N3904). The transistor actually caused it to supply less amperage so my thought is that it has something to do with the amount of current the MOSFETs and transistors are allowing to flow through them. My question is, why am I seeing such a small amount of amperage on the output of the transformer? Also, is this design safe since 10mA isn't fatal and the human body would provide some resistance lowing that number a bit more?

Datasheets:
[Transformer](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/177/160-161-1389957.pdf)
[MOSFET](https://static6.arrow.com/aropdfconversion/70d61058b6a2126367cb502e9e2fb78aebec174f/irlz44npbf.pdf)
[555 Timer](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/na555.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Why have you bothered with a 5V buck converter? The 555 runs happily from 12V and you stand a better chance of turning on the MOSFET properly.

Comment: 2mA can be fatal if it hits at the "right" well, wrong, time in the heart beat cycle...

Comment: In the future I'm planning to use this circuit with an Arduino. The 5v side of things in this circuit will be powered off the supply voltage of the Arduino.

Comment: That design is "not entirely unsafe" if the switching frequency is at least 1kHz. Muscles cannot follow such a high frequency. Still, there are dielectric effects which makes it unhealthy to touch the high voltage side.

Comment: It is doubtful that your current meter can show you anything useful at the (aproximately) 1.5kHz the 555 is oscillating at.

Comment: Yeah, I wondered about that. I don't have documentation for it any more but It's probably only meant for 60Hz. How can I properly measure it? Or is there a way I can determine it mathematically?

Comment: What current are you expecting to get from this circuit? And at what voltage?

Comment: I only need a few mA out of this circuit (5-10). It actually works really well for my application. I only expected to get 276 volts since this transformer is intended to step down 230v to 10 and I have it wired in reverse (23 * 12 = 276).

Comment: If you've got a buck controller, and assuming you don't need galvanic isolation: why not abuse the buck converter controller as flyback controller, and everything but the buck and the transformer from your circuit?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I'm not following can you elaborate?

Comment: what a buck converter does is switch an inductor with a mosfet to achieve a desired output voltage over that inductor. That entails a control loop that charges the magnetic field (i.e. lets current flow) of the inductor until the desired output voltage has been reached, which often is measured using a resistive voltage divider. When you use a transformer's primary side in place of the simple inductor, and put the voltage divider on the secondary side, you've basically built a flyback converter which allows you to even achieve higher voltages than you put in.

Comment: in fact, knowing the transformer, you can even do primary-side control

Comment: Ok, I think I follow most of that. I'd struggle a bit with building it. However, I still like this design, the reason being that I can put a digital rheostat in place of the 500 ohm resistor and control the resistance with a microcontroller which will in turn alter the frequency of the 555 timer and finally the change the color of the EL paint. At this point I'm mostly looking for a way to make this circuit safe so that it would be impossible to kill myself or another.